# How to pass data between many View Controllers without using Singletons?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, singleton, uikit

Let's say I have a `Car` object with standard attributes like color, model, brand, and number of seats.

Each view controller in my app would be responsible for getting each of those attributes until the end:

Color View Controller --> Model View Controller --> Brand View Controller --> Seats Controller --> Result Controller

The way I pass data between each controller right now is through a Singleton, but I've read online that is is an anti-pattern and creates a lot of coupling later. Question is then: what is the best way for me to funnel all of the data to `Result Controller`?

Comment: Use `NSUserDefaults` to store data, it can be accessed in all classes.

Comment: That's just as bad as using a singleton.. If not worse.

Comment: Make one SuperClass and inherit that super class to all SubClass (Here: View Controller --> Model View Controller --> Brand View Controller --> Seats Controller --> Result Controller).

Comment: You could create a model class for data objects and hold the data in there and access it by creating an instance of that class in Result Controller.

Comment: @7ball  If data are transient then it is a good idea to have a simple singleton model class.

Comment: @7ball you can use a model class intense and it can  be pass to new ViewController and after setting value for current ViewController

Comment: Singleton pattern creates tight couple and complex when the object gets large. To avoid this, use Dependency Injection. It is a pattern used to share state across your program when you to avoid singletons and global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your singletons to services.
For example: your singleton `StateManager` has two method: `set(state: SomeState)` and `getState() -> State`.

First, use protocols:

```
protocol StateManager: class {
    func set(state: SomeState)
    func getStatus() -> SomeState
}
```

Second, your app modules shouldn't know about witch `StateManager` they use:

```
class MyAppController: UIViewController {
    var stateManager: StateManager?

    ...
}
```

And when you init your VC:

```
let vc = MyAppController()
vc.stateManager = ConcreteStateManager.sharedInstance
//present vc
```

If you have a centralized place for create VC, you can hold instance of `ConcreteStateManager` in it, without calling `sharedInstance`.

Also, read about **Dependency injection** in swift.